# Cant render to Frame Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

I try to render a small quad on a bigger quad but it doesn't seem to work. It renders both quads a small magenta quad and a big white quad with a line on it, on next to each other, not one on top of the other.

```
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

float *data = new float[ 756 * 756 * 3 ];

for( int i = 0 ; i < 756 ; i++ )
    for( int j = 0 ; j < 756 ; j++ )
        if( i == j )
            for( int k = 0; k < 3 ; k++ )
                data[i * 756 * 3 + j * 3 + k] = 0.0f;
        else
            for( int k = 0; k < 3 ; k++ )
                data[ i * 756 * 3 + j * 3 + k ] = 1.0f;

GLuint Texture;
GLuint FrameBufferObject;

glGenTextures( 1 , &Texture );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , Texture );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , 3 , 756 , 756 , 0 , GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT , data );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 );

glewInit();

glGenFramebuffers( 1 , &FrameBufferObject );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , FrameBufferObject );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , Texture );

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture, 0);

//GLuint atchements[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
//glDrawBuffers( 1 , atchements );

GLenum e = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (e != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        cout << " MASIVE ERROR, ABORT ! " << endl;

glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER , 0 );

/* program main loop */
while (!bQuit)
{
    /* check for messages */
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        /* handle or dispatch messages */
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            bQuit = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glLoadIdentity();

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 );

        glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_BUFFER , FrameBufferObject );

        //GLuint atchements[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
        //glDrawBuffers( 1 , atchements );

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 );
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f( 1 , 0 , 1 );

            glVertex2f( 0 , 0 );
            glVertex2f( 0 , .1 );
            glVertex2f( .1 , .1 );
            glVertex2f( .1 , 0 );

            glColor3f( 1 , 1 , 1 );
        glEnd();

        glBindFramebuffer( GL_DRAW_BUFFER , 0 );

        glScalef( 0.5 , .5 , .5 );
        glTranslatef( 0 , 0.3 , 0 );

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D , Texture );
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

            glTexCoord2f( 0 , 0 );
            glVertex2f( 0 , 0 );

            glTexCoord2f( 0 , 1 );
            glVertex2f( 0 , 1 );

            glTexCoord2f( 1 , 1 );
            glVertex2f( 1 , 1 );

            glTexCoord2f( 1 , 0 );
            glVertex2f( 1 , 0 );

        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        SwapBuffers(hDC);

        theta += 1.0f;
        Sleep (1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, but I think the main issue is that you are not using `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` correctly. This is *not* to read from the texture you rendered into, but just the source operand for `glBlitFramebuffer()`. It is totally irrelevant here.

What you currently are doing in the main loop:

1. set the FBO as draw framebuffer, so rendering to `Texture`
2. clear it
3. draw some quad with magenta color, texturing still enabled, but texture object 0 bound
4. *still leave the FBO bound as draw framebuffer*
5. you bind the FBO as read framebuffer also, which is of no use here
6. render a white quad textured with the texture you rendered into in 2&3

Step 4&6 in combination create an invalid *feedback loop*, since you still render into `Texture` at this point. You never render onto the screen, so you shouldn't see anything at all. The fact that you do actually see something besides a black screen means that I overlooked some other error, because you shouldn't. (**EDIT**: The OP noticed that he originally wrote `glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_BUFFER,...)` instead of `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, which now fully explains the observed behavior.)

You probably want `glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,0)` instead of step 4&5, to render into the default framebuffer again.

Some other issues:

- you never adjust the viewport size to match that of the framebuffer you are using
- you reattach the texture to the FBO repeatedly
- you use an array of floats to specify the initial texture, although your internal format is just an 8bit per channel normalized uint format

Comment: Ok so you are right about the errors, I've not seen them, but after I fixed them the program behaves the same. I've not fix the viewport, is there any reason this should be the problem ? Also I don't understand why do you say that my format is of 8bit per channel, isn't here the place where I set it : "glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , 3 , 756 , 756 , 0 , GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT , data );"?

Comment: As you said, I shouldn't see the purple square if not the entire scene. But it seems like it is completely ignoring the fact that I'm drawing to the fbo.

Comment: @user3727118: that is just the format your data is organised in client memory. What the GPU will use is what you set as `internalFormat`. You just put 3 there, which is an old, deprecated shortcut for specifying `GL_RGB`, which is just standard 8bit per channel integers. If you really want a float format, you must use something like `GL_RGB32F`.

Comment: oh, then I dont see why I get a perfect diagonal on my white rectangle, but I dont think that is the place from where the problem comes.

Comment: @user3727118: the data is converted from the client format to the the internal format, so the texture itself appears correct, uou just have a pointless data conversion inbeetween. But yes, this is not your main issue. And I still don't know why it behaves as you describe. Is the FBO actually framebuffer-complete? Does checking for GL errors reveal something?

Comment: found it, it was GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER not GL_DRAW_BUFFER

Comment: @user3727118: hmm, I seem to have skimmed over your code too quickly and did not read carefully enough. I updated my answer accordingly.